# Update nested property of object in an array

Tags: typescript

I have an object that looks like this:

```
data: {
  users: [
    {
      id: "someString",
      liquidityPositions: [
        {
          balance: "someString",
          pair: {
            id: "someString",
            reserve0: "someString",
            reserve1: "someString",
            token0: {
                      id: "someString"
            },
            token1: {
                      id: "someString"
            },
          }
        },

        ...
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to change the property of `token0` and `token1` to include an extra property `symbol`:

```
let updated = myObj.data.user[0].liquidityPositions.map(
    (liquidityPosition) => ({
        ...balance,
        //I'm not sure how to update here
```

How can I add a new property to `token0` and `token1` while preserving everything else?

Comment: Did you want only first element of users or like all elements of users? Like you are getting first element of users and then mapping liquidityPositions

Comment: the `user` property is an array but it will only have one element

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it like this.

```
data.users[0].liquidityPositions.map(({pair, ...rest}) => {
  const token0 = {...pair.token0, symbol: 'asdf'};
  const token1 = {...pair.token1, symbol: 'qwerty'};
  return {...rest, pair: {...pair, token0, token1}};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not so concise, but it seems to work

```js
let updated = data.users[0].liquidityPositions.map((liquidityPosition) => {
    let oldPair = liquidityPosition.pair
    return {
        ...liquidityPosition,
        pair: {
            ...oldPair,
            token0: {
                ...oldPair.token0,
                id: "newString"
            },
            token1: {
                ...oldPair.token1,
                id: "newString"
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Also you can just inline the old reference, if you want

```js
let updated = data.users[0].liquidityPositions.map((liquidityPosition) => ({
    ...liquidityPosition,
    pair: {
        ...liquidityPosition.pair,
        token0: {
            ...liquidityPosition.pair.token0,
            id: "newString"
        },
        token1: {
            ...liquidityPosition.pair.token1,
            id: "newString"
        }
    }
}))
```